# Convert MySQLi into PDO with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I apologize if I am not posting this in the right place. I wanted to know if I converted this correctly. I am trying to convert all my code in PDO.

Here is the mySQLi:

```
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($timestamp);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    return ($timestamp);
```

I changed it to:

```
$stmt->execute();
$timestamp = $stmt->fetch();
return ($timestamp);
```

Can someone tell me if I did this right?

Comment: You'd have your answer if you'd have tried running that.

Comment: Wow, really? Now every one wants to down vote my questions. I see absolutely nothing wrong with my questions, but once again there is no help to a legitimate question.

Comment: FWIW @iamthestreets, your questions prior to this have been fine, and either have an unvoted or positive vote score. So, don't worry about this DV blip! No-one avoids downvotes here entirely.

Comment: @halfer Thanks! I really do appreciate the help I get here. Sometimes it just gets frustrating.

Comment: No problem. Whilst it may not have been phrased as diplomatically as it could be, the feedback on these questions yesterday is basically good: if you can show as much effort/research as possible, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$stmt` is your connection parameter...then

```
$query = $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$query->execute();
$timestamp = $query->fetchAll();
```

Try it with an example you will get to know...

Or

```
$query = $stmt->query("select * from table");
$timestamp = $query->fetch();
```

Comment: So there is no need to do `return`?

Comment: if you are using it in a function...then I guess you would need one...else if you just need to echo the output...`return` wont be needed..

Comment: @iamthestreets: I'd add to this that a `prepare()` is a good idea if you are (1) injecting user input into a query, in a `WHERE` clause, or (2) wanting to run the query more than once. If neither of those apply, you can just use the `query()` method.